# Nested intervals theorem for open intervals

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

Let's try to prove [nested intervals theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_intervals) for $\textbf{open}$ intervals. Suppose, we have an $\textbf{infinite}$ sequence of nested intervals:

$$I_1 \supset I_2 \supset I_3 \supset ...$$

Suppose, that for some step $k$ we got:
$$I_1 \cap \ I_2 \ \cap \ ... \cap \ I_k = \emptyset$$

Because of inclusions we can have it $\textbf{only}$ when $I_k = \emptyset$. But this will mean, that there is no step $k+1$ because there is no such $I_{k+1}$ that $I_{k+1} \subset \emptyset = I_k$. So our sequence is finite. But the condition states that it is infinite! So there is no such "bad" step, on which we get an empty set. If there is no such bad step, then we $\textit{always}$ have something in the intersection.

So the theorem works for open intervals, but we have a famous counterexample:

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\ (0, \frac{1}{n}) = \emptyset$$

So the question is: where is the mistake in my proof?

Comment: Perhaps you should state more precisely what you are trying to prove.  You say this is a proof "by contradiction", but you have assumed that you reach an empty intersection in a finite number of steps.  Since the intervals are nested, it is indeed possible only if $I_k = \emptyset$.  But what exactly does this contradict?  At a glance you assume the sequence is finite and conclude the sequence is finite.

Comment: Finiteness of our sequence contradicts with the condition, that we have an **infinte** sequence of nested intervals.

Comment: Sure, but that is not how proof by contradiction works.  I can't simply pick a "theorem", then write down an assumption contrary to what the theorem sets out, and claim that I've proved something by contradiction.  For example, *I want to prove $x = 0$.  Assume $x \neq 0$.  Contradiction.*  It doesn't really prove anything, does it?

Comment: Which assumption is contrary to the theorem? I tried to show, that there is no such step, on which we get an empty set. If there is no such step, then we always have something in the intersection

Comment: But what you've assumed (that the empty intersection is reached in a finite number of steps) does *not* follow from the assumption that the infinite nested intersection is empty.  Instead this assumption that the intersection of some initial $k$ intervals is empty is tantamount (as you pointed out) to assuming that the $k$th interval is empty.  Throwing in such an additional assumption is not justified by appealing to "proof by contradiction."  Indeed it is possible for the infinite intersection to be empty while each finite number of intervals have nonempty intersection as your example shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That attempt to prove "by contradiction" something like the Nested Interval Theorem for open intervals (rather than closed ones) is invalidated by introducing an extra assumption other than the one for which a contradiction is sought.

The proof by contradiction allows us to assume that the infinite nested intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ is empty.  But in addition to that supposition, the claimed proof introduces a stronger claim, that the emptiness is achieved by some finite step, $I_1 \cap I_2 \cap \ldots I_n = \emptyset$.

However, as the "proof" correctly points out, this amounts to assuming that one of the intervals $I_n = \emptyset$, a conclusion we cannot validly reach from the original premise that the intersection of infinitely many nested open intervals is empty.

The example $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (0,1/n) = \emptyset$ illustrates this "overreach", since none of the countably many open intervals involved is actually empty.

The idea in this attempt does suffice to prove that the intersection of *finitely* many *nonempty* nested open intervals is not empty (and the assumption that they are open is not used, so it can be omitted).